# Images in front of a border

Tags: html, css, border, z-index

this is what I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwKfE.jpg
Three hours passed and I still can't figure it out how to do this. I've tried everything with positions and z-index but nothing works. I really don't want to use everything in a single image(border + pictures) and using it as a background because I'm trying to do a responsive website. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the effort that you've done already?

Comment: can you provide us the fiddle for a good understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to understand your question, but without real examples it's very difficult to uderstand:

Anyway, here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whaxvj85/) which I've created which I do believe is what you need.

I do have a container with a padding, which is holding another container with a border. On top of that particular border an image is showed.

The above example is achieved by using z-index and relative positioning:

```
img { position: relative; z-index: 100; top: 100px; left: -30px; }
```